# Needing to Export results from Powershell to Excel

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell and trying to see how I can export the results in the powershell script to an excel file.

Here is the script i'm using so far.

```
###Upgrade###

####Text File Location###### 

$YourFile = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\PowerShell\target.txt'
foreach ($computer in $YourFile) {

####Ram Check#####

Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory -Computername $computer | Format-Table PScomputername,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity -autosize 

}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Instead of `Format-Table` you use `Export-Csv` with the according parameters. Please read the complete help including the examples to learn how to use it [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7). Regardless of that - there are literally thousands of examples even here on SO. Use the search you find on top of this site.  ;-)

Comment: Ditto to what Olaf is saying, and point of note, [there are dozens of Youtube videos on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+export+to+excel) and [tons of Powershell training](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+beginning) since you say you are new.

Comment: Yea think i will give up on this. Did research on this for about 4 hours and still no luck that's why i asked and was the main reason for creating this account on stackoverflow. Just better off typing my original code in power shell then copying and pasting result in to excel or using vbs. Thinks for the help though.

Comment: Really? I even described what to do and you're still not able to use this? Then it might be better to give up.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you need to learn and try on your own. As long as you try and share your attempts I will try to help.  You made a descent question. I know that you only want one file that contains all the ram information. I gave you one csv per computer. hint: -append.  I gave all properties of the class even know you only wanted a few. Hint: Select-Object then save to file.  Every developer that tries gets stuck for a few hours at least once a week.

**NEVER GIVE UP**

```
    #Text File Location######
        $YourFile = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\PowerShell\target.txt'

        foreach ($computer in $YourFile) {

        # Ram Check
        # "Format-Table PScomputername,Banklabel,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity -autosize"  
        # only prints to the screen and will stop you from sending the info to a file. 
        # Save the contents to of the win32_physicalmemory class to the variable $PMEM
        $PMem = Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory -Computername $computer
        # export the powershell object to CSV file
        $PMem | Export-csv -Path "$env:TEMP\$($PMem.PSComputerName).csv"  -NoTypeInformation
        # print the location of the file to the screen
        Write-host "The csv file was saved: $env:TEMP\$($PMem.PSComputerName).csv" 
        }

        Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```